# Proving $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am given the properties of a field and told that $\mathbb{Q}=\{\frac{a}{b}: a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\, b\neq 0\}$ I have to show the $\mathbb{Q}$ satisfy them all, can I use both the addition and multiplication operations?

For example to prove the addition commutativity can I say:

$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}= \frac{ad}{bd}+\frac{cb}{bd}=\frac{ad+cb}{bd}=\frac{cb+ad}{bd}=\frac{cb}{bd}+\frac{ad}{bd}=\frac{c}{d}+\frac{a}{b}$$

Comment: What is your definition of $\Bbb Q$ ? For me this is the _field_ of fractions of $\Bbb Z$…

Comment: Yes, it highly depends on your definitions, and what you already know.

Comment: @Watson for the qeustion, $\mathbb{Q}$ are all the numbers $\frac{a}{b}$ such that $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b\neq 0$

Comment: All of the field axioms? Is it granted that it's a ring, or must you prove that too? It shouldn't be too hard, just tedious.

Comment: @gbox What is a number $\frac{a}{b}$ defined as? Are you taking a pre-existing field $\mathbb{R}$ and trying to work out whether a specific subset is a subfield, or are you building $\mathbb{Q}$ from the ground up?

Comment: Can you use that $\mathbb{R}$ is a field? Then you just have to check that $\mathbb{Q}$ is "closed".

Comment: I can use the fact the $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, sorry if I was misunderstood

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say that you are allowed to use that $\mathbb{R}$ is a field.

Therefore all you need to show is that addition and multiplication of two rational numbers does not take you out of the rationals, because then $\mathbb{Q}$ inherits all the other field properties from $\mathbb{R}$.